# Changes in properties using beforeUpdate seems to have no effect on extended classes?

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

we have the following domain class inheritance strategy.

- AbstractDomain (containts default properties)
- User extends AbstractDomain
- Operator extends User

In the AbstractDomain we have made methods to implement the
beforeUpdate and beforeInsert using methods so we can extends these on
extending classes

AbsrtractDomain

```
abstract class AbstractDomain {
    protected void onBeforeInsert() {
    ...
    }

    protected void onBeforeUpdate() {
    ...
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        onBeforeInsert()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        onBeforeUpdate()
    }
}
```

In the user class we have the logic the encrypt the users password like this..

User

```
public class User extends AbstractDomain {
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeUpdate() {
        super.onBeforeUpdate()
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        println "encoding password!!!!"
        if (springSecurityService) { // added the if clause to ensure
that tests work correct!
            password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
        }
    }
}
```

Operator

```
public class Operator extends User {
// code omitted
}
```

So when i try to update a operator, is see the message "encoding
password!!!!" the property is set, but when i check the DB the
password is still in clear text ..
The changes i make seem to have no effect and seem not to be persisted.

Any clue what i may be missing?

Comment: Hi Bill, you nailed it totally!! I have made the mistake of using 'def springSecurityService' in the AbstractDomain class and also in the User class. So the one in the User class was null!! Please provide an answer so i can accept you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code... if you see the "encoding password!!!" text, but the password is not encoded, then either the springSecurityService property is NOT set, or the encodePassword function failed to work... this has nothing to do with inheritance. I would move your println INSIDE the if, since that's more accurate.